# How to create a secure "Contact me" form in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help,

I need to add a "Contact me" form to my website, most of tutorials almost use the same approach, but all of them don't work properly; instead of receiving the visitor message I receive a security problem warning like this:
[image]

Here is the code I used (outlook and gmail interact in the same way):

//this the event handler of the send button

```
protected void ButtonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {

    string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Message.txt");
    string mailBody = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

    mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Name##", TextBoxName.Text);
    mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Email##", TextBoxEmail.Text);
    mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Subject##", TextBoxSubject.Text);
    mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Body##", TextBoxBody.Text);
    MailMessage visitorMessage = new MailMessage();
    visitorMessage.Subject = "New Message: " + TextBoxSubject.Text;
    visitorMessage.Body = mailBody;

    visitorMessage.From = new MailAddress(TextBoxEmail.Text, TextBoxName.Text);
    visitorMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("asdfg@outlook.com", "Mohamed"));
    visitorMessage.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(TextBoxEmail.Text));
    SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    mySmtpClient.Send(visitorMessage);
    LabelIRespond.Visible = true;

}
}
```

and for web.config:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="Mohamed &lt;asdfg@outlook.com&gt;">
        <network host="Smtp.live.com" port="587" enableSsl="true" userName="asdfg@outlook.com" password="myOutlookPassword" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Please help me figure out what am I missing here, no one talk about this issue when they create such forms, I hope I find the solution here?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks to be a security issue with outlook.com - check their settings to see if you're able to send using the SMTP

Comment: Man, that has nothing to do with the form, read the error, Google is blocking your server from sending emails with that account. Using google for bulk send is always very problematic, use your own SMTP server.

Comment: If you use outlook or gmail the name has to be an exact match with the name registered to the account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most email services will fight you **hard** on allowing an application to log in and use it programmatically like this (in fact I think many have Terms of Use which prohibit this). This is how spammers would use a service to spam people if they could. Instead you need to find a service that will allow you to send emails via an API, or set up your own SMTP server.

I would suggest something like SendGrid: https://sendgrid.com/pricing, they have a free plan that includes 12,000 emails per month.

Comment: I can't see this free plan, the the minimum plan is the essential ($9.95/ mo).

Comment: Scroll to the bottom, under the heading `Not sure how much you’ll send?`.

Comment: Oh I see it now, thanks, I'll try it. do you suggest any tutorial on how to use it in my ASP.NET project?

Comment: I've never used it, but a quick search turns up: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/csharp.html